# Is there a way to convert the mathematica document into word document in a neat way?

Tags: save, format

Is there a way to convert the mathematica document into word document in a neat way?

I tried by "save as" command and found something like Risk text format "*.rtf"

but still many parts look messy..

Comment: rtf = rich text format

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much!